# Get value of a public static field via reflection

Tags: c#, .net

This is what I've done so far:

```
 var fields = typeof (Settings.Lookup).GetFields();
 Console.WriteLine(fields[0].GetValue(Settings.Lookup)); 
         // Compile error, Class Name is not valid at this point
```

And this is my static class:

```
public static class Settings
{
   public static class Lookup
   {
      public static string F1 ="abc";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You need to pass `null` to `GetValue`, since this field doesn't belong to any instance:

```cs
fields[0].GetValue(null)
```

Answer (score 32):

You need to use Type.GetField(System.Reflection.BindingFlags) overload:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx

For example:

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(Settings.Lookup).GetField("Lookup", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

Settings.Lookup lookup = (Settings.Lookup)field.GetValue(null);
```

Comment: For some reason I had to add these flags for it to work: `BindingFlags.Static |  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`

Answer (score 8):

The signature of `FieldInfo.GetValue` is

```
public abstract Object GetValue(
    Object obj
)
```

where `obj` is the object instance you want to retrieve the value from or `null` if it's a static class. So this should do:

```
var props = typeof (Settings.Lookup).GetFields();
Console.WriteLine(props[0].GetValue(null));
```

Comment: Don't trust variable names... the OP is calling GetFields, not GetProperties ;)

Comment: @PauliØsterø what does the second `null` correspond to? Does not [`FieldInfo.GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) only accept a single parameter? I can't seem to find overloads of `GetValue` or anything

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow mere typo, its fixed now

Comment: @PauliØsterø thought so :) just wanted to make sure the code in the question is copy-paste ready. So +1 for a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Settings.Lookup).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
    object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(null); // value = "abc"
```