# How can i find a specific element/field in the class

Tags: c#, button, findcontrol

I have 2 page app. First page MainPage, and second page is class and name "Links". I have buttons in mainpage. and i have string variables in "Links" with the same name as the buttons.
***For example***

```
class Links
{      
    public static string a1 = "data1";
    public static string a2 = "data2";
    public static string a3 = "data3";
}

//Main page
public partial class MainPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void allclickevents(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Button x = (Button)sender;
       string findthisname=x.Content.ToString();
       //I need to find the string data of the same name in "Links" class. And show messagebox, for ex if button a2 messagebox shows "data2".
    }
}
```

**Design Page(Xaml page):**

```
<Button x:Name="a1" Content="a1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="allclickevents"/>
<Button x:Name="a2" Content="a2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="allclickevents"/>
<Button x:Name="a3" Content="a3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="460,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="allclickevents"/>
```

All buttons click events set to `allclickevents` method, and i am use (Button). sender and find specific button name. Need only find same named string data in Links class. 
I need to find the string data of the same name in "Links" class. And show messagebox, for ex if button a2 messagebox shows `data2`. Please help.

Comment: does `x` have a Name or ID property after you declare an Instance of it..? if Button has a `Tag` Property then you can do the following as well `var name = ((Button)sender).Tag;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is via reflection, which is a pretty good indicator that its *not* the right approach to solving the overall problem.

That being said, the following code will do it:

```
string data = (string) typeof(Links).GetField(findthisname).GetValue(null);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee(v=vs.110).aspx) for `GetField` and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898385/get-value-of-a-public-static-field-via-reflection) for how to use it to access static members.

To get the message box, just use `MessageBox.Show(data)`.

Comment: But string data is not object
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?),
İ am try var data = typeof(Linkler).GetField(findthisname); but only have datatype(in messagebox) output: "string[]"

Comment: @DesperadoMurat Yes, using reflection you need to explictily cast to the correct type (another reason its not the right approach!) updated my answer to add it

Comment: its work! good job thanks for answer, and sorry i am noob not know somethinks:)
I try this and work perfect:
string[] data =
 (string [])typeof(Linkler).GetField(findthisname).GetValue(null); ;
            MessageBox.Show(data[0]);

Comment: @DesperadoMurat I would expect that to work. Since you are still learning, I would try and find an approach that *didn't* require reflection. You'll end up with a better design and better code if you do!

Answer (score 0):

```
        FieldInfo f_key = typeof(Links).GetField(p);
        var o = f_key.GetValue(null);
```

these code should work, but if you use Dictionary,it will be much easier,like this:

```
        Dictionary<String,String> links = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        links.Add("a1","data1");
        links.Add("a2", "data2");
        links.Add("a3", "data3");
```

when you use it :

`links["ai"]` will return `"datai"`

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this answer. You provide a good suggestion (the dictionary), though he may have a good reason for it being in a separate object. The reflection code is messed up though, the variable names are bad and you don't need to instantiate a "Links" object (the fields are static). If you improve it I would consider upvoting.