# C# Reflection of a class field

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I searched but didn't find correct answer.

Assume that we have a class like:

```
public sealed Class Foo{
     public static readonly Foo x;
     public static readonly Foo y;
     public static readonly Foo z;
     public static readonly Foo t;

     public string Name{get;}
     public int Value{get;}
     public Foo(string name,int val){//properties sets here}
}
```

And I have an `enum` like:

```
public enum FooFinder{
  x,
  y,
  z,
  t
}
```

this Foo class in a different library called `FooLib.dll` and `FooFinder` created by me.

I want to return Foo.x, Foo.y types using my enum class.

```
 private static Foo GetFoo (FooFinder Level)
    {
        FieldInfo[] props = typeof(Foo).GetFields();

        foreach (FieldInfo item in props)
        {

            if (item.Name == Enum.GetName(typeof(FooFinder), Level))
            {
                 // I could create an instance of Foo with Activator.CreateInstance() 
                 // but I want to return Foo class' chosen field by FooFinder enum
            }
        }

    }
```

I hope I could explain what I want to do. So how can I get Foo class' chosen field by reflection? or Can I get?

Comment: Could be [useful to know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx). As for question, you don't pass instance to the method, so it must take instance from somewhere. Only you know from where.

Comment: What is the type of all these static fields (x, y, z, t)?

Comment: You meant you want to get the _static value_ of that field or are you having trouble finding the right field?  If so then it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898385)

Comment: "I searched but didn't find correct answer." What did you search for?  The top 4 search results for search results [c# reflection get static field value](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20reflection%20get%20static%20field%20value) all seem to have valid answers.

Comment: @Verarind I added type of field. (Thank you)

Comment: @DStanley I want to return "Foo.x" or "Foo.y" itself as object. Not value of Foo.x. I could create an instance of Foo class but I want instance of one of Foo class' field.

Comment: @CagdasA I'm still confused.  You mean the _string_ "Foo.x"?  The type of `x` _is_ a `Foo` so returning it's _value_ will give you a `Foo` instance (assuming it's been set to a valid value somewhere).

Comment: @DStanley I didn't mean any string things. I'm new at here and I'm just learning how to use this site. Sorry about that. <br/> I want to `Foo.x` as return object not class of `Foo`. <br/> Consider that `Foo` is using for designating a level. For example `log4net.Core.Level` has 17 field like `Level.All`, `Level.Info`,`Level.Off` etc. to determine the level of logging. I want to return `Level` class' chosen field by passing `enum` parameter. For example I call `GetFoo` method with `FooFinder.x` parameter. And I want `GetFoo` metod to return `Foo.x` object. Is it possible?

Comment: @CagdasA I'm sorry, but I still don't understand the distinction between "Foo.x" and the _value_ of the static field `x` that you'd get from reflection.  Either I'm missing something or you expect them to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
private static Foo GetFoo (FooFinder Level)
{
    var fieldInfo = typeof(Foo).GetField(Enum.GetName(typeof(FooFinder), level), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    return fieldInfo?.GetValue(null) as Foo;
}
```